# Having hard time working with ArrayForm : adding form field

Tags: arrays, angular, dialog

I'm trying to display add a playlist in Mat-dialog that has songs in a list using (formArray) like this: 
[image]

but I don't what mistake I'm making

my dialogue look this way:

[image]
here's my code:

my Dialog.component.html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Create New Playlist
</h1>
<form [formGroup]='form'>
<div>

  <div mat-dialog-content>


      <mat-form-field class="input-width" appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Playlist name</mat-label>
        <input  matInput placeholder="" required formControlName="name"  [(ngModel)]="data.name">

      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field class="input-width" appearance="standard">
        <mat-label>Description</mat-label>
        <input  matInput placeholder="" required formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="data.description" >

      </mat-form-field>



  <div formArrayName="songs" >
    <div *ngFor = "let song of form.controls.songs?.value; let i = index">
      <div class="song-input-wrapper" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-form-field  appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Song Title</mat-label>
          <input  matInput placeholder="" required formControlName="title">

        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field  appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Artist</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="" required formControlName="artist">

        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
          <mat-label>Duration</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" required  formControlName="duration">
          <span matSuffix>minutes</span>
        </mat-form-field>
          <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="addSong()">
            <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button
          *ngIf="form.controls.songs?.value > 1"
          mat-icon-button
          color="warn"
          (click)="removeSong(i)"
        >
          <mat-icon>remove_circle</mat-icon>
        </button>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>



  </div>
         <mat-dialog-actions class="action-buttons">
    <button mat-raised-button  color="warn" (click)="close()" >Cancel </button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary"  [disabled] = "form.invalid" (click)="onSubmit()" [mat-dialog-close]="data">Submit</button>

  </mat-dialog-actions>  
</form>
```

and my dialog.componenet.ts:

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit {

  description:string;
  songs: FormArray;
  constructor(public service: PlaylistService,public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Playlist  ) 
   { 
   }

   form : FormGroup = new FormGroup(
    {
      name:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      title:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      artist:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      duration:new FormControl(0,[Validators.required , Validators.min(0)]),
      songs:  this.formBuilder.array([  ])


    }
  )

  songsform() :FormArray { 
    return this.form.get('songs') as FormArray ;
  }
  addCreds() {
    const creds = this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
    creds.push(this.formBuilder.group({
      title:'',
      artist: '',
      duration: 0,
    }));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

      }


  close() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}

createSong(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    title: [null, Validators.required],
    artist: [null, Validators.required],
    duration: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0)])],
  });
}
addSong(): void {
  this.songs.push(this.createSong());
}
removeSong(index: number): void {
  if (this.songs.controls.length > 1) {
    this.songs.removeAt(index);
  }
}
  onSubmit(){

      this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);

  }  
  }
```

and finally, the component where I open the dialog and where my playlist class exist:

```
export interface Playlist {
  name: string;
  totalDuration: number;
  totalSongs: number;
  description: string;
  songs: Song[];
}

export interface Song {
  title: string;
  artist: string;
  duration: number;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-playlist',
  templateUrl: './playlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playlist.component.css']
})

export class PlaylistComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,public service: PlaylistService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }



  playlists: Playlist[] = [
    {
      name: 'Kopikustik',
      totalDuration: 5,
      totalSongs: 2,
      description: 'More than a coffee, this is all of your favorite accoustic songs.',
      songs: [
        {
          title: 'Cigarettes of ours',
          artist: 'Ardhito Pramono',
          duration: 3
        },
        {
          title: 'Walking Back Home',
          artist: 'Vira Talisa',
          duration: 2
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Anime Hits',
      totalDuration: 13,
      totalSongs: 3,
      description: 'Listen to your favorite Anime songs, all in one playlist.',
      songs: [
        {
          title: 'Renai Circulation',
          artist: 'Kana Hanazawa',
          duration: 4
        },
        {
          title: 'Platinum Disco',
          artist: 'Tsukihi Phoenix',
          duration: 4
        },
        {
          title: 'Silhouette',
          artist: 'KANA-BOON',
          duration: 5
        },
      ]
    }
  ];
  name:String
  @Input() data: Playlist
  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = false;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {

      width: '900px',
      data: {
        name : this.name,
      songs: []
      }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
      if (result) {
        this.name = result.name;
        alert("name is :"+ this.name)
        }
    });
  }

  deletePlaylist(i)
  {
    this.playlists.splice(i, 1);
  }

}
```

if anyone is familiar or can see what I'm missing please help me 
I've been for a similar solution and example but I always get the same interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields), it looks like you need to set a form group instance inside your array item when the form is created, the place where you create your form. Try this on ngOnInit():

```
form : FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      name:new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      description:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      title:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      artist:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
      duration:new FormControl(0,[Validators.required , Validators.min(0)]),
      songs:  this.formBuilder.array([ this.createSong() ])
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you it did work but I got "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"  I will look for the problem and thank you for the article :)

Comment: Great. Ts code looks right. It must be a template the problem.  Probably is a data binding issue, check  formControlName in every input tag in HTML code.

Comment: Thank you very much it was a stupid mistake the function name is wrong :)